# Как убрать всплыващую подсказку в Javascript VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При написании какого-либо метода JS, всплывает навязчивая подсказка - попробовал множество способов исправить это, но ничего не помогло. От отчаяния решил сам всё-таки задать вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Я поэкспериментировал, и у меня получилось.

Не знаю, какая именно из трех настроек сыграла роль, но в совокупности они дали ныжный результат.

Итак, я добавил три параметра:

```
    "editor.hover.enabled": false,
    "editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 1000,
    "editor.parameterHints": false
```

Ну, и история в картинках:

[image: шаг1]

[image: шаг2]

[image: шаг3]

Comment: отключил всё, не помогло

Comment: Я поменял ответ, у меня тот способ, котрый сейчас в ответе - сработал